# logback: how to set logging level per thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, logback

I have a multithreaded Java application, each thread being a class extending a base class extending Thread. One of the threads occasionally gives a method in the base class a large amount of machine-generated data, while the others only give small trickles of human-typed data. I want to log those human-typed messages on a higher loglevel than the machine data, but as the base class is part of all threads I cannot distinguish that in the code.

One solution is to inform the base class from the extended classes to log on a different level, but then I'd have to hardcode that knowledge into the application, which is ugly.

What I would like to do is "steer" this through my logback.xml config.

I wrote a small reproducer:

```
package x.y.z;
import org.slf4j.*;

public class Quickie {
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Quickie.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MyThread t1 = new MyThread("hi");
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread("bye"); 

        t1.start(); t2.start();
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyThread.class);

    public MyThread(final String name) { this.setName(name); }

    public void run() { logSomething(); }

    public void logSomething() {
        LOG.trace(getName()); LOG.error(getName());
    }
}
```

This is the logback config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss} %-6level %-10([%thread]) %logger{1}.%method:%line %message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

With most importantly, the encoder pattern being:

```
            <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss} %-6level %-10([%thread]) %logger{1}.%method:%line %message%n</pattern>
```

As this shows the thread clearly:

```
11:16:09 TRACE  [bye]      c.t.k.t.MyThread.logSomething:24 bye
11:16:09 TRACE  [hi]       c.t.k.t.MyThread.logSomething:24 hi
11:16:09 ERROR  [bye]      c.t.k.t.MyThread.logSomething:24 bye
11:16:09 ERROR  [hi]       c.t.k.t.MyThread.logSomething:24 hi
```

... I would say there should be a way to configure my logback.xml have the "bye" thread only log on info or higher, while the "hi" thread logs from trace or higher? I spend half a day googling and reading logback documentation and I tried sifters and regex filters and lots of other examples, but they all just go on the message, apparently. Meaning that one solution could be to have a magical string appear in the messages and filter that out, but that too would be ugly.

So, is there a way to steer log levels per thread from within the log configuration without having to inject "specialized code" into the application?

Comment: This sounds like a really good case for using markers.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use MDC and TurboFilter for this purpose.

Add a call of `MDC.put()` in `run()` method like this:

```java
public void run() {
    MDC.put("threadname", this.getName());
    logSomething();
}
```

If you want to the "bye" thread only log on info or higher and the "hi" thread logs from trace or higher, you have to add a definition of DynamicThresholdFilter to `logback.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
  <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.DynamicThresholdFilter">
    <Key>threadname</Key>
    <!-- You can set default threshold as you like -->
    <DefaultThreshold>TRACE</DefaultThreshold>
    <MDCValueLevelPair>
      <value>bye</value>
      <level>info</level>
    </MDCValueLevelPair>
    <MDCValueLevelPair>
      <value>hi</value>
      <level>trace</level>
    </MDCValueLevelPair>
  </turboFilter>
  ......
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In such case I think you need to declare another appender & logger with threshold info. Since appender itself has no idea of from what threads it will be called.

Comment: But there's a %thread in the appender pattern and that works (see pattern and log output in my question), so it must be aware of the thread, right? That's what my hope was mostly based on...